# Tensorflow exponential decay learning rate seems not to work

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, optimization, neural-network

I have built a neural network with tensorflow and it looks as follows:

```
n_hidden = 32
steps = 10**5*4
decay_rate = 1e-4
initial_lr = 1e-3

tf.reset_default_graph()
g = tf.Graph()

dropout_rate = tf.placeholder_with_default(0.2, (), name='dropout')
curr_step = tf.placeholder_with_default(1, (), name='current_step')
learning_rate = tf.train.exponential_decay(initial_lr, global_step=curr_step, decay_steps=steps,
                                           decay_rate=decay_rate, name='learning_rate')

X_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, X.shape[1]], name='X_input')
y_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None], name='y_input')

w = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([X.shape[1], n_hidden]), name='w_0')
b = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal([n_hidden]), name='b_0')
product = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(X_tensor, tf.nn.dropout(w, rate=dropout_rate, name='w_0_dropout'),
                                     name='matmul_0') + tf.nn.dropout(b, rate=dropout_rate, name='b_0_dropout'),
                           name='activation_0')

w_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, n_hidden]), name='w_1')
b_1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden]), name='b_1')
product_1 = tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(product, tf.nn.dropout(w_1, rate=dropout_rate, name='w_1_dropout'),
                                       name='matmul_1') + tf.nn.dropout(b_1, rate=dropout_rate, name='b_1_dropout'),
                             name='activation_1')

w_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_hidden, 1]), name='w_2')
b_2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]), name='b_2')
product_2 = tf.reshape(tf.nn.leaky_relu(tf.matmul(product_1, tf.nn.dropout(w_2, rate=dropout_rate,
                                                                           name='w_2_dropout'),
                                                  name='matmul_2') + b_2, name='activation_2'), [-1],
                       name='reshape')
cost = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(labels=y_tensor, predictions=product_2)

#correct_predictions = tf.equal(tf.argmax(product, axis=1), y_tensor)
#accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float64))
mae = tf.losses.absolute_difference(y_tensor, product_2)
correct_predictions = tf.equal(tf.cast(tf.round(product_2), tf.int64), y_tensor, name='correct')
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_predictions, tf.float64), name='accuracy')
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate, name='optimizer').minimize(cost)
```

Even when I decrease learning rate to worthless (1e-100), the loss anyway fluctuates:

```
Step 2500, Minibatch Loss= 2.8308, Training Accuracy= 0.2525, Training MAE= 1.3107, lr= 0.00000000000000
Step 5000, Minibatch Loss= 2.7827, Training Accuracy= 0.2664, Training MAE= 1.2948, lr= 0.00000000000000
Step 7500, Minibatch Loss= 2.6718, Training Accuracy= 0.2481, Training MAE= 1.2784, lr= 0.00000000000000
Step 10000, Minibatch Loss= 2.6464, Training Accuracy= 0.2603, Training MAE= 1.2718, lr= 0.00000000000000
Step 12500, Minibatch Loss= 2.8204, Training Accuracy= 0.2614, Training MAE= 1.3014, lr= 0.00000000000000
```

Maybe I have mixed up something? All the data is scaled, so lr=1e-100 cannot influence, although it does.

Will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the parameters fluctuate though? You don't display your execution code, however, it is quite possible, that all the metrics that are displayed are only **an average over all the batches seen in the current epoch**. That would mean that the first row is average over 2500 batches, the second row would be average over 5000 batches, etc.

This would explain the fluctuation. So try printing out your parameters after epochs, if they are indeed changing too, you can eliminate this hypothesis.